# Cannot concatenate Keras Lambda layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I need to process some layers in a different way, doing some OR operations. I've found how to do it, I create a Lambda Layer and process the data with `keras.backend.any`. I am also doing a split, because I need to operate 2 separates groups with my logical OR.

```
def logical_or_layer(x):
    """Processing an OR operation"""
    import keras.backend
    #normalized to 0,1 
    aux_array = keras.backend.sign(x)
    aux_array = keras.backend.relu(aux_array)
    # OR operation
    aux_array = keras.backend.any(aux_array)
    # casting back the True/False to 1,0
    aux_array = keras.backend.cast(aux_array, dtype='float32')

    return aux_array
```

Then I'am creating my layers like this:

```
#this is the input tensor
inputs = Input(shape=(inputSize,))

#this is the Neurule layer
x = Dense(neurulesQt, activation='softsign')(inputs)
#after each neurule layer, the outputs need to be put into SIGNUM (-1 or 1)
x = Lambda(signumTransform, output_shape=lambda x:x, name='signumAfterNeurules')(x)

#separating into 2 (2 possible outputs)
layer_split0 = Lambda( lambda x: x[:, :end_output0], output_shape=(11, ), name='layer_split0')(x)
layer_split1 = Lambda( lambda x: x[:, start_output1:end_output1], output_shape=(9,), name='layer_split1')(x)

#this is the OR layer
y_0 = Lambda(logical_or_layer, output_shape=(1,), name='or0')(layer_split0)
y_1 = Lambda(logical_or_layer, output_shape=(1,), name='or1')(layer_split1)
```

Just FYI: Neurules are Neurons created based on IF-THEN rules, that's one project to work with Neurons which were trained with a TruthTable, representing Expert Knowledge.

Now, when I try to put the splitted layers back like this:

```
y = concatenate([y_0,y_1])
```

This error comes:

```
ValueError: Can't concatenate scalars (use tf.stack instead) for 'concatenate_32/concat' (op: 'ConcatV2') with input shapes: [], [], [].
```

Then ok, let's use the `tf.stack` as suggested:

```
y = keras.backend.stack([y_0, y_1])
```

Then it can't be used as an output in the Model anymore, when I try:

```
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=y)
```

Comes the error:

```
ValueError: Output tensors to a Model must be the output of a Keras `Layer` (thus holding past layer metadata). Found: Tensor("stack_14:0", shape=(2,), dtype=float32)
```

Checking with the function `keras.backend.is_keras_tensor(y)` it gives me `False`, but with all the other layers it gives me `True`

How should I concatenate it correctly?

**EDIT:** Following the answer from @today I was able to create a new Lambda Layer with the `stack` wrapped inside of it. But the outputs are modified, it should be `(None,2)` and it is `(2,None,1)` here is the output from `model.summary()`:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_90 (InputLayer)           (None, 24)           0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_90 (Dense)                (None, 20)           500         input_90[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
signumAfterNeurules (Lambda)    (None, 20)           0           dense_90[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
layer_split0 (Lambda)           (None, 11)           0           signumAfterNeurules[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
layer_split1 (Lambda)           (None, 9)            0           signumAfterNeurules[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
or0 (Lambda)                    (None, 1)            0           layer_split0[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
or1 (Lambda)                    (None, 1)            0           layer_split1[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
output (Lambda)                 (2, None, 1)         0           or0[0][0]                        
                                                                 or1[0][0]                        
==================================================================================================
Total params: 500
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 500
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

How should I define the output_shape in the layers to have the batch still there at the end?

**EDIT2:** Following the tips from @today I've done the following:

```
#this is the input tensor
inputs = Input(shape=(inputSize,))

#this is the Neurule layer
x = Dense(neurulesQt, activation='softsign')(inputs)
#after each neuron layer, the outputs need to be put into SIGNUM (-1 or 1)
x = Lambda(signumTransform, output_shape=lambda x:x, name='signumAfterNeurules')(x)
#separating into 2 (2 possible outputs)
layer_split0 = Lambda( lambda x: x[:, :end_output0], output_shape=[11], name='layer_split0')(x)    
layer_split1 = Lambda( lambda x: x[:, start_output1:end_output1], output_shape=[9], name='layer_split1')(x)
#this is the OR layer
y_0 = Lambda(logical_or_layer, output_shape=(1,), name='or0')(layer_split0)
y_1 = Lambda(logical_or_layer, output_shape=(1,), name='or1')(layer_split1)

y = Lambda(lambda x: K.stack([x[0], x[1]]),output_shape=(2,),  name="output")([y_0, y_1])
```

Now it seems to work correctly, the `model.summary()` below:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            (None, 24)           0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 20)           500         input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
signumAfterNeurules (Lambda)    (None, 20)           0           dense_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
layer_split0 (Lambda)           (None, 11)           0           signumAfterNeurules[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
layer_split1 (Lambda)           (None, 9)            0           signumAfterNeurules[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
or0 (Lambda)                    (None, 1)            0           layer_split0[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
or1 (Lambda)                    (None, 1)            0           layer_split1[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
output (Lambda)                 (None, 2)            0           or0[0][0]                        
                                                                 or1[0][0]                        
==================================================================================================
Total params: 500
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 500
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the `K.stack` inside a `Lambda` layer like this:

```
from keras import backend as K

y = Lambda(lambda x: K.stack([x[0], x[1]]))([y_0, y_1])
```

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to wrap the `stack` inside the Lambdas already created and nothing happened...but as you said, I need to create one more layer and do it inside it, now it's working.

Comment: The problem now is like I'm having a `output_shape=(2,)` and it should be `(None,2)`, but I can't add it as a parameter, it gives me an error `IndexError: tuple index out of range`

Comment: @Vinicius It is caused by other parts of the model, probably your custom layers. It seems you are not preserving the batch axis.

Comment: I've tried to modify the `output_shapes`with no success, I've edited the question with the `model.summary()` output, do you know what should I change now?

Comment: @Vinicius I don't think you need to use `K.stack` at all. The output of your layers should preserve the batch axis. Change `output_shape` argument of `or0` and `or1` layers to `(None, 1)` and then use `concatenate` layer instead. If you would like to use `K.stack` you can set its `axis` argument to `-1`, however I recommend the `concatenate` layer.

Comment: if I try to `concatenate` with this `output_shape=(None, 1)` it also gives me the same error: `ValueError: Can't concatenate scalars (use tf.stack instead) for 'concatenate_33/concat' (op: 'ConcatV2') with input shapes: [], [], [].`

Comment: @Vinicius What if you fix the output shape of all the other Lambda layers?